# Custom SQL queries in PerformancePoint DashBoard designer

Tags: sql, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

Is it possible to utilize the data that is returned by a CUSSTOM SQL query on a database to create the DasshBoard elements ?

So far i was ablle to connect to a specific Table and use it in AS IS form ( no interaction with multible tables )

Any pointers in this topic would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
IP.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a View in your database and creating a datasource that connects to that view.  The view would join all the tables you need.

**Edit**:
If you don't have permissions to create a view, you still have some options:

1. stand up a SQL box you control, create a linked server to the one you don't, and create the view in your control
2. create an Access database, with a linked table to the tables you want.  create your view there, and use that as your ODBC datasource in dashboard designer.
3. Give to the DBA the query you want and ask them to create the view for you.  If you have permissions to create the query, there should be no problem creating the view (better performance, stability of the data, etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But,
What can i do if i DON hav access to create views on the DB ?